# split a multidimentional array into new a set of simple arrays by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I would like to split by key, Ideally I would like to create new named arrays dynamically from the key values of the multidimensional array.

logically, I assume I need to get the keys, and then for each key loop through the multidimensioal array and push the values of corresponding key for that iteration onto the new array.

each inner array is quite large, and ideally i would like to set this up so that if that array changes its number of pairs this will still function.

I feel like I know some of the ingredients here, but just can't seem to put it together.

Example array:

```
$data = Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 0
        [id] => 221
        [title] => Home
        [latitude] => -34.0284224
        [longitude] => 18.46636710000007
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [id] => 321
        [title] => office
        [latitude] => -34.0284224
        [longitude] => 18.46636710000007
    ),
    [2] => Array
    (
        [count] => 2
        [id] => 124
        [title] => storage
        [latitude] => -34.0284224
        [longitude] => 18.46636710000007

    )
)
```

and what I'd like to produce is :

```
$count = array(0,1,2);
$id = array(221,321,124);
$title = array('home','office','storage');
```

etc etc

any and all help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: what was the edit george ?

Comment: Pro tip: if you click on the *edited x mins ago*, you can see the edit history for a post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) seem to be what you're looking for:

```
foreach($data as $element) {
    foreach($element as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($$key)) {
            $$key = array();
        }

        array_push($$key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get exactly this, Mark raises a good point though about not 'knowing' the variables names in a dynamic situation, and while I like the array_column bit, this is what I was after with this question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >=5.5, then [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can do this for you:

```
$count = array_column($data, 'count');
$id = array_column($data, 'id');
$title = array_column($data, 'title');
```

To make it more generic:

```
foreach($data[0] as $key => $value) {
    $$key = array_column($data, $key);
}
```

but the danger here is that you don't necessarily know the names of the variables that you're creating

so a more-generic-still

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($data[0] as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = array_column($data, $key);
}
```

may be more workable

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, however the OP does say `each inner array is quite large, and ideally i would like to set this up so that if that array changes its number of pairs this will still function.`..

Comment: That is true but the second 2 examples seems quite workable in that situation, I didn't know about array_column, very nice indeed.  I will probably use this solution, though Georges answer is more well matched to the way I phrased my question, thank you so much for the awesome effort and insight.